# User ALTER TABLE ... CONCATENATE with partial matching partitions in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to use the ALTER TABLE ... CONCATENATE functionality in Hive, but it seems I have to give exact partition name. For example I have a table with two partition columns, date and group. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
alter table mytable partition (insert_date='2017-04-11',group='%') CONCATENATE;
```

But i can't find the way of doing it.

Comment: we need to define partition individually , may be you can write shell script to do all in a loop

Comment: Yes, Im doing something similar, just wanted to know if there is any way around it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate doesn't support this.